# Does not getting the table <td> element style height:100% to <div> element in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am giving the table and div height, width has 100%.  element get the 100% height but when it reach div which present in  then div does not  height 100%. In chrome and IE this working fine, only getting problem in Firefox. Is that I am doing anything wrong or it's problem of browser please help!

**Syntax**:

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;background-color:yellow;border:solid black;">
<table style="height:100%;width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background-color:red;border:solid black;">      
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/7wa7wrkk/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also faced same problem in past, I think this is problem of Firefox browser  only not fault of your code because it not applying 100% height of  to ! In your case simple way handle your problem by giving "Height:100%" style to  element. By this way it will work in all browser without any issue.

**Syntax**:

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;background-color:yellow;border:solid black;">
<table style="height:100%;width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;">
      <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background-color:red;border:solid black;">      
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/7wa7wrkk/5/

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Thanks for helping your answer solved my confusion plus issue.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to assign the 100% `height` to the `td`:

https://jsfiddle.net/yfehv1da/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Johannes I think both of you helped me!